# Cordova run with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

I'm making an Android app with the framework Cordova. It's all right until the command "cordova run". The terminal gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/MainActivity-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /home/francesco/hello/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
francesco@francesco:~/hello$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
LGOTMS79a92e5a  device
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you install your app from a different PC / Play Store previously?

Comment: This can happen if you are attempting to load a debug version (which run defaults to) over top of a release built version of the application.

Comment: Not really. It can also happen when you install the same version but from a different PC. The certificates are just diferrent.

Comment: Cordova made ​​me install the API 21 and the last SDK platforms . The cell on which loading the application uses Android 4.2

Comment: How can you solve the problem of inconsistent certificates? Thank you for your help